# How to check if $valueInput2 is equal with the generated value ? My code is returning a false value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if $valueInput2 is equal with the generated value ? My code is returning a false value.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var $buttonValue = $(".value_generate"); 
 var $divValue = $(".generated_value");
 var $generatedP = $(".generated_p");
 var $valueInput2 = $(".value_input_2");
 var $submitPages2 = $(".submit_pages_2");
   
   function valueGenerator(value) {
      var valueString="";
      var lettersNumbers="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
   for(var i = 0; i < value; i++) 
   valueString += lettersNumbers.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()* lettersNumbers.length));
   return valueString;} // generate a random value

   $buttonValue.click(function generate() {
  var $key = valueGenerator(12);
  $generatedP.html($key);
 });  // click to display the generated value
 
   $submitPages2.click(function() {
 if($valueInput2 == $generatedP.html() ){
  alert("yes");
 } else {
  alert("no");
 }
});  // check if input == generated value
```

I am new to jquery

Comment: You are comparing a jQuery object to a String of text. You need `$valueInput2.val()` or `$valueInput2.html()`.

Comment: or maybe `$valueInput2[0].outerHTML`

Comment: Great! Thank you.